# TypeScript: Type 'ActionTypes' does not satisfy the constraint 'Action<any>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-thunk, typescript-generics

I am writing a TypeScript application using React and Redux and am having a problem.

I need a second default option.

Here is the code:

```js
import { ThunkAction } from 'redux-thunk'
type AppThunk<ActionTypes, ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<
  ReturnType,
  AppStateType,
  unknown,
  ActionTypes
>
type ActionTypes = followUnfollowActionType | setUsersActionType | setTotalCountActionType |
  setCurrentPageActionType | toggleIsFetchingActionType | toggleFollowingInProgressActionType
type ThunkType = AppThunk<ActionTypes>
```

Error:

```
Type 'ActionTypes' does not satisfy the constraint 'Action<any>'.  TS2344

    6 |   AppStateType,
    7 |   unknown,
  > 8 |   ActionTypes
      |   ^
    9 | >
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

I already found a solution:

```js
import { AppStateType } from '../redux/store'
import { ThunkAction } from 'redux-thunk'
import { Action } from 'redux'

export type AppThunk<ActionTypes extends Action, ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<
  ReturnType,
  AppStateType,
  unknown,
  ActionTypes
>
```